# A good way to store data of a person in Java?

Tags: java, data-storage

I would like to store some data such as first name, last name, date of birth, address, telephone number, etc.  There will probably be about 50 fields in total.  What would be a good way to store that data? I was thinking of just using a class named Person and put bunch of members in it for the fields.  Ex:

```
public class Person {
    private String fName;
    private String mName;
    private String lName;
    private String dob;
    private String address;
    private String phNumber;
    private String sex;
    private String aka;
    // etc...
    public void setfName(String st) {
        fName = st;
    }
    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }
    // etc....
}
```

Is there a better way to perform this task?

**EDIT:**

I should also mention that each of the data fields will be (hopefully if I figure out how to do it) inserted into a Microsoft Word template.  I'm not necessarily planning on working with the data beyond that scope.  What I have at this moment is a pdf document, which I was able to extract text from.  I will parse that text and attempt to get all the data out of it.  I will then insert that data into the word template (if it's possible).

Comment: just an opinion here, it seems fine. in case you plan to store fine grained details in properties such as `address`, `dob` and others, you could also make separate object for those.

Comment: I'd look at separating related data, such as contact details, which could be added to a list instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what your needs are.

Using a `String` for every piece of information is probably a bad idea. You should use appropriate data types for the information you're storing.

- A [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instance for date of birth
- An [`enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for gender
- A custom class for addresses which has fields for house number, street, unit number, city, state, zip code, etc.

Comment: I didn't even know about the Calendar, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could store them in a hashmap:

```
private Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

public void insertData(String key, String value)
{
    data.put(key, value);
}

public String lookup(String key)
{
    return data.get(key);
}
```

```
insertData("fName", "blah blah");
insertData("address", "blah blah");

String address = lookup("address");
```

You could get a list of all available keys like this:

```
Set<String> keys = data.keySet();
```

---

Another option is to use the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: A sensible idea, but that wouldn't enforce the content structure unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, hashmap looks interesting.

Comment: So, a HashMap can only contain a certain key type and a certain key data?  What I mean is that if I set them as <String, String>, I won't be able to insert integer data in that HashMap, right?

Comment: Hmm... well, I guess I can use the HashMap table for most of the stuff and then only a few of data fields would require boolean values, which I can do separately.  Luckily, I'm extracting text and shoving it back into another file, so Strings might be the only thing I'd have to work with, even when it comes to numbers.  I'm trying to make lives of our filing clerics easier... heh  So I'm trying to make a program to help them.